# How to make iCloud overwrite an older iCal file

Tags: macos, icloud

Unlike some users here, I want iCloud to overwrite my iCal files on an older Mac that I am just now upgrading. The older iCal files are out of date on this computer, although my other devices (and iCloud) are up-to-date.

So, how do I make sure that the older Mac is updated by iCloud instead of merging?

My guess is that I should first delete my old files on the older Mac. Is this the best way?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want a merge, then the best idea would be – like you proposed – to delete all calendar data on your old Mac while it's not connected to iCloud, and then re-enable syncing.

I don't see any other reasonable way to achieve this.